# One pipeline to fit both Text and Categorical features

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to find a way to use one Pipeline to transform a Text feature and a Categorical feature then fit them to a classifier.

The working example below (**simplified for readability**) is the method I am using currently.

I have to split into 3 mini Pipelines or variables :

1. The first will encode the categorical feature,
2. The second will apply Tfidf Vectorizer on raw_text feature,
3. The third will fit classifier to the combined data (after combining both features using `hstack`)

> ```
> from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder
> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
> import scipy
>
> raw_text_tr = ["kjndn ndoabn mbba odb ob b dboa \n onbn abf  ppfjpfap",
>             "ùodnaionf àjùfnàehna nbn obeùfoenen",
>             "ùodnaionf àjùfnàehna nbn obeùfoenen dfa e g aze",
>             "fjp ,fj)jea ghàhàhà àhàtgjjaz çujàh e ghghàugàh çàéhg \n\n\n\n oddn duhodd"]
> categorie_tr = ["cat1","cat2","cat2","cat4"]
> target_tr = ["no","no","no","yes"]
>
> raw_text_te = ["ldkdl jaoldldj doizd test yes ok manufajddk p",
>             "\n\n\n dopj pdjj pdjaj ada  ohdha hdçh dmamad ldidl h dohdodz"]
> categorie_te = ["cat3","cat5"]
>
> train_df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(raw_text_tr, categorie_tr, target_tr)),columns=["raw_text_ft","categorical_ft","target"])
> test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(raw_text_te, categorie_te)),columns=["raw_text_ft","categorical_ft"])
> print(train_df)
> #                                          raw_text_ft categorical_ft target
> # 0  kjndn ndoabn mbba odb ob b dboa \n onbn abf  p...           cat1     no
> # 1                ùodnaionf àjùfnàehna nbn obeùfoenen           cat2     no
> # 2    ùodnaionf àjùfnàehna nbn obeùfoenen dfa e g aze           cat2     no
> # 3  fjp ,fj)jea ghàhàhà àhàtgjjaz çujàh e ghghàugà...           cat4    yes
>
> print(test_df)
> #                                          raw_text_ft categorical_ft
> # 0      ldkdl jaoldldj doizd test yes ok manufajddk p           cat3
> # 1  \n\n\n dopj pdjj pdjaj ada  ohdha hdçh dmamad ...           cat5
>
> pipeline_tfidf = Pipeline([("tfidf",TfidfVectorizer())])
> pipeline_enc = Pipeline([("enc",OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])
> pipeline_clf = Pipeline([("clf",LogisticRegression())])
>
> A_tr = pipeline_tfidf.fit_transform(train_df["raw_text_ft"])
> B_tr = pipeline_enc.fit_transform(train_df["categorical_ft"].values.reshape(-1,1))
> X_train = scipy.sparse.hstack([A_tr,B_tr])
>
> A_te = pipeline_tfidf.transform(test_df["raw_text_ft"])
> B_te = pipeline_enc.transform(test_df["categorical_ft"].values.reshape(-1,1))
> X_test = scipy.sparse.hstack([A_te,B_te])
>
> pipeline_clf.fit(X_train, train_df["target"])
> ```

Is there a cleaner way to put all these steps inside only one Pipeline ?

Below is a Pipeline I imagined but is not currently working, I am using `FeatureUnion` to combine both transformed features before classification

```
pipeline_tot = Pipeline([
  ('features', FeatureUnion([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('enc', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))
  ])),
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])
```

The hard part is how to split the Text and Categorical features when fitting the Pipeline (I can give only one element to the pipeline_tot.fit() function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) concatinates transformations each applied to the whole feature set, while
[`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) applies transformations separately to particular feature
subsets you specify:

```py
>>> from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
...     transformers=[
...         ('text', TfidfVectorizer(), 'raw_text_ft'), #TfidfVectorizer accepts column name only between quotes
...         ('category', OneHotEncoder(), ['categorical_ft']),
...     ],
... )
>>> pipe = Pipeline(
...     steps=[
...         ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
...         ('classifier', LogisticRegression()),
...     ],
... )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested your solution but had an error in dimensions linked to TfidfVectorizer. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54704747/7358899 the column has to be 'raw_text_ft' instead of ['raw_text_ft']. Finally worked for me !

Comment: @snat2100 Good catch!