# How do I resolve the "ValueError: not enough values to unpack" in this sklearn code?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Setting up a basic pipeline for Titanic Kaggle data, but am getting the error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`.

While there are a handful of SO posts on this error, they don't quite line up, or provide solid method for diagnosing this problem, let alone a solution.  The error's traceback is vague, unfortunately. I've commented out most lines and rerun the code to see if I could narrow down which

Here's a sample of the data:

```
PassengerId Pclass  Sex     Age     SibSp   Parch   Fare    Embarked    Title
892           3     male    34.5      0       0     7.8292      Q       Mr
893           3     female  47.0      1       0     7.0000      S       Mrs
894           2     male    62.0      0       0     9.6875      Q       Mr
895           3     male    27.0      0       0     8.6625      S       Mr
896           3     female  22.0      1       1     12.2875     S       Mrs
```

Here's the pipeline code I'm working with:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


#Create a column transformer to impute missing values and one-hot encode specific columns
col_transform = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                                                ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False), ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'Title']), 
                                                ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))], 
                                  remainder='passthrough')

#Create a pipeline for the column transformer and logistic regressor
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('encoding', col_transform),
                       ('logistic_reg', LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, tol=0.1))])
param_grid = {
#     'logistic_reg__class_weight':[None, 'balanced'],
#     'logistic_reg__solver':['lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'newton-cg']
}

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)

best_clf=clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

*Question:*  Any ideas why I'm getting the error mentioned above?

*EDIT:*  Here's the full error

```
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 516, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 352, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 317, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 355, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 716, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 472, in fit_transform
    self._validate_transformers()
  File "C:\Users\Lofgran\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 265, in _validate_transformers
    names, transformers, _ = zip(*self.transformers)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6a051cf930ab> in <module>
     25 clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1) #5 fold cross-validation; n_jobs=use all processors
     26 
---> 27 best_clf=clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    686                 return results
    687 
--> 688             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    689 
    690         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1147     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1148         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1149         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1150 
   1151 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    665                                for parameters, (train, test)
    666                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 667                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    668 
    669                 if len(out) < 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    932 
    933             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
--> 934                 self.retrieve()
    935             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    936             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    831             try:
    832                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 833                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    834                 else:
    835                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    519         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    520         try:
--> 521             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    522         except LokyTimeoutError:
    523             raise TimeoutError()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

*Edit 2:*

```
col_transform = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[ 
                                                ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')),
                                                ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False))], 
                                  remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: Can you post the Error message as is? What line it refers to?

Comment: Full error has been posted, as requested.  Short answer: it refers to line 27 (the `.fit` line)

Comment: You have at least 2 issues with your code: (1) `('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False), ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'Title'])`. OHE doesn't work on list of columns, you should pass columns one by one. (2) `('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'))`, this is where your error message fires because you have a tuple of 2 whereas sklearn expects a tuple of 3 (add list of columns here). The real problem is that your code won't run even after correcting the errors. `ColumnTransformer` is simply a shame.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - my list of column names is what's supposed to be encoded, while another (unlisted) column needed to be imputed. Maybe there was some misunderstanding there. Disregarding that, your comment has merit. I changed the code you mentioned to be as shown in *Edit 2* in the question above, however, I get an error: `ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Don'] in column 2 during transform` (referenced to the same `.fit()` line as mentioned above.  'Don' is a value in my 'Title' column. So I guess the Title column either wasn't encoded properly or didn't drop the unencoded values?

Comment: The fact that you want to OHE encode the list of columns doesn't count... OHE doesn't accept list of columns, you have to do on a column by column basis. Read docs carefully or see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54694923/columntransformer-with-tfidfvectorizer-produces-empty-vocabulary-error). Your other error is due to the fact that OHE sees different tokens in train and test. Adjust params accordingly. And even after that `ColumnTransformer` won't work....

Comment: If you deal with the original `titanic.csv`, `Age` is not the only column with missing values. You have a long way to debug your code...

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - In my dataset, Age is actually the only column with missing values at this point (I've done a lot of other prep work that this problem doesn't include), but your point on that matter is outside the scope of this question.  I understand that the OHE doesn't take columns (and I've checked the documentation many times) - I thought I'd been putting the columns into the `ColumnTransformer`, but I guess I'd missed it by a bracket.  In any case,when I remove all column lists altogether (see revised edit 2 above), the original problem remains.

Comment: Your directions have not led to any resolutions, so I'm inclined to believe that the problem is with something else.  Can you clarify, or suggest another option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that have run across the same problem, here's what I've figured out:  The syntax of the transformers inside the `ColumnTransformer` is critical. They must be numbers, and for the `OneHotEncoder`, it must apparently be in the `slice(x, y,...z)` format, with the arguments being integer column numbers (I tried to add it as a list and tuple, and neither worked).  Sergey Bushmanov had the first bit right (that my imputer wasn't functioning because I didn't specify the column correctly, but there'd been no indication as to how the `OneHotEncoder` issue should be resolved, so I'm marking this answer as correct.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(
                       [("imputer", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median'), [2]),
                        ("one_hot", OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False), slice(1, 6, 7))])
```