# Error of preparation of data before fitting

Tags: scikit-learn, spacy

> ValueError: 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data.

Here I'm trying to Text Classify `'text'` and as a second feature the `'setting'` into `'target'`.

I don't understand the meaning of this error, I believe I did everything right.

Data is 2D!

Text is a string, setting is a string (but I want it categorical).

```py
def BoW_tokenizer(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    tokens = [token for token in doc if not (token.is_stop or token.is_punct)]
    tokens = [token.lemma_.lower() if token.lemma_ != "-PRON-"
              else token.text.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens

bow_vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=BoW_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1, 2))
tfidf_vec = TfidfTransformer()
lsvc = LinearSVC()

X = train_df[['text', 'setting']]
y = train_df['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=8)


preproc = ColumnTransformer([('bow & tf-idf',
                              make_pipeline(bow_vec, tfidf_vec),
                              ['text']),
                              ('OrdinalEncoder',
                              OrdinalEncoder(),
                              ['setting'])])

pipe = make_pipeline(preproc, lsvc)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

Can someone help me?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 457, in _fit_transform
        self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1007, in __call__
        while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 835, in dispatch_one_batch
        self._dispatch(tasks)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 754, in _dispatch
        job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 209, in apply_async
        result = ImmediateResult(func)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 590, in __init__
        self.results = batch()
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
        for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
        for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 728, in _fit_transform_one
        res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 574, in fit_transform
        return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 629, in fit
        self._fit(X)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 74, in _fit
        X_list, n_samples, n_features = self._check_X(X)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 43, in _check_X
        X_temp = check_array(X, dtype=None)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 556, in check_array
        "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
    array=['play' 'iot' 'transport' ... 'news' 'play' 'calendar'].
    Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/Desktop/Hackaton - NLP/Py_Scratch.py", line 122, in <module>
        pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 350, in fit
        Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 315, in _fit
        **fit_params_steps[name])
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 355, in __call__
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 728, in _fit_transform_one
        res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 518, in fit_transform
        result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
      File "/Users/alessiomassini/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 460, in _fit_transform
        raise ValueError(_ERR_MSG_1DCOLUMN)
    ValueError: 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a scalar.
```

Comment: Also, I've got this question I couldn't figure out:
Does **.fit()** on a Pipeline perform also **.transform()** on transformers?
Because if it just fits then transformers are not "used".
I think that logically .fit() on a pipeline should .fit_transform() all steps before the final classifier which should be just .fit().

**Can someone confirm that .fit() on a Pipeline does not just .fit() ?**

Comment: yes, it will do `.fit_transform` on all the steps before the final estimator when you call `.fit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the `['text']` to `'text'`, because the vectorizers take 1D iterator of strings only. You can get more discussions on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54694923/columntransformer-with-tfidfvectorizer-produces-empty-vocabulary-error)

Some reproducible example for your code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import spacy

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

cats = ['alt.atheism', 'sci.space']

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=cats)

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': newsgroups_train.data, 'target': newsgroups_train.target})
df['setting'] = np.random.choice(['play','iot','transport', 'news', 'play', 'calendar'], len(df))
print(df.head())

def BoW_tokenizer(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    tokens = [token for token in doc if not (token.is_stop or token.is_punct)]
    tokens = [token.lemma_.lower() if token.lemma_ != "-PRON-"
              else token.text.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens

bow_vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=BoW_tokenizer)
tfidf_vec = TfidfTransformer()
lsvc = LinearSVC()

X = df[['text','setting']]
y = df['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.7,
                                                    random_state=8)

preproc = ColumnTransformer([('bow & tf-idf',
                              make_pipeline(bow_vec, tfidf_vec),
                              'text'),
                             ('OrdinalEncoder',
                              OrdinalEncoder(),
                              ['setting'])])

pipe = make_pipeline(preproc, lsvc)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = pipe.predict(X_test)
```